Handling CORS in React Native
I have a FastAPI backend running and want to protect any URL using my endpoint with CORS. With a web app, it's simple; you just need to accept requests that match your frontend URL. However, how would you handle this in an Expo React Native app since there isn't a static frontend URL?

Did you try just making the call? SOP/CORS is only a client side protection, so if your client doesn't care about CORS, there is no issue with FastAPI not allowing through SOP with CORS for any other client.
